# Experiment With C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 99;
    printf("%d %d\n",1 > scanf("%d",&x) ? scanf("%d",&x): scanf("%d",&x),x);
}
```

So What is happening to the scanned values.
Lets say First Input is 11. so left most scanf is returning 1. So according to the rule the right most scanf will be executed. But The right most %d of printf is not printing the scanned value. It is showing 99.

Comment: There is no way this should appear in production code. At best, it explores the very edge of the official specifications (which could be a good thing). At worst, you randomly concatenate functions and operators and then ask us "why is this happening to me?"

Comment: Are you really trying to call `scanf`, twice, using a `?:` operator, inside the argument list of a `printf` call?  Perhaps it was just an intellectual exercise, but this would be a super bad idea even if it did work, which in this case, it doesn't.

Comment: yes because this is a place to know a computer for a computer lover. you are people with information and wisdom . everyone should ask you. and experiments leads to some discovery . I didn't know that "sequence point" thing before that. but now i will check on this.

Comment: Discoveries are done on the unexplored areas. But this area is well explored. Moreover, it is not some natural phenomena, it is made by people according to specifications. So any question you might have is answered by these specifications. Experiments is not a good way to find out these specifications, as once you have a UB, you might get different results for the same experiment.

Comment: well..that was a discovery from my perspective , and I got your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *unidefined behavior*.

That is because you are modifying a value and accessing that value without an intervening *sequence point*. A simplified example with the same problem:

```
int x, y;
x = 1;
y = scanf("%d", &x) + x; /* <--- UB! */
```

Or also:

```
int x = 1;
printf("%d %d", x = 11, x); /* <--- UB! */
```

Note that while the `?:` does insert a sequence point just after the condition, the comma that separates arguments in a function call does not. This measn, not only that the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, but also that you must not modify the same value twice in the arguments of a function, or modify and use the same argument.

For example this other example is also UB:

```
int x = 0;
printf("%d %d", x++, x); /* <--- UB! */
```

Or this one:

```
int x[10] = {0}, i = 0;
printf("%d %d", x[i++], x[i++]); /* <--- UB! */
```

The solution for your problem is to separate the code in nice orderly sentences. A full sentence always ends with a sequence point!

```
int x = 99;
int y = 1 > scanf("%d",&x) ? scanf("%d",&x): scanf("%d",&x); /* ARGH! */
printf("%d %d\n", y, x);
```

Now, the line marked with the exclamation is quite nonsensical, but at least it is UB-free.

Comment: Well, I will check on that..I am glad that someone is sharing information..

Comment: and +1, virtually though. coz my reputation is not high enough to vote you.

Comment: @ParnabSanyal: Thanks, but you are the OP, so you can (should) accept one answer (mine or other's) by clicking on the empty check under the vote arrows.

Comment: one thing for
printf("%d %d ",x++,x);
we can say that execution is taking place from right most side. Can't we?

Comment: @ParnabSanyal No. In general the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. But here the problem is the modify&use without sequence point, and that is UB, that is anything may happen.

Comment: @ParnabSanyal: No.  The compiler is free to evaluate the arguments to `printf` in any order if feels like.  There are only a few places where C *guarantees* a specific order of evaluation (execution) within an expression; otherwise, the order of evaluation is *unspecified*.

Comment: ya I saw that when you did the arr[i++] thing. and yes it is UB. but the thing is for only printf("%d %d %d %d",--x,x--,x++,x++)  the result is following a pattern to be executed from right to left. anyway..thanks for all that

Comment: @ParnabSanyal: Also remember that *undefined behavior* simply means that the compiler is not required to handle the situation in a particular way.  The compiler may reject the code outright.  Or it may generate the executable and issue a bunch of warnings.  Or it may not issue any warnings at all.  The generated machine code may crash outright, or it may give bad or unexpected output, or it may run without any (apparent) issues.

Comment: @ParnabSanyal: If you're seeing *any* kind of a pattern in that `printf` statement, it's only by coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments may be evaluated in any order. In this case, it looks like x evaluates to 99 before scanf is called. The order of function argument evaluation is unspecified in C. This is [C FAQ #3.7](http://c-faq.com/expr/comma.html):

> The comma operator does guarantee left-to-right evaluation, but the commas separating the arguments in a function call are not comma operators. [...] The order of evaluation of the arguments to a function call is unspecified.

Because there is no sequence point between the scanf that *modifies* x and the function argument that *evaluates* it, you are invoking undefined behavior, as explained in rodrigo's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link